# 'Settings' object has no attribute 'EMAIL_HOST_USESR'

Tags: python, django, email, web, gmail

I wanna send email by django and gmail smtp and I see this error.

the code below is my email setting

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'MY EMAIL'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'MY PASSWORD'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

i expect to send email without any problems

Answer (score 1):

Case1: To send emails through Gmail SMTP in Django, you need to configure your Gmail account to allow access to less secure apps.
You can find this option in your Google account settings under the "Security" section.
There you can find "Allow less secure apps."

Case2: You might have a typo in your Django Settings.
'Settings' object has no attribute 'EMAIL_HOST_USESR'
The USESR is your typo.

Comment: I know but it is not possible anymore and Google has disabled this option. but I use 16 password and it is Ok

Comment: @ابراهیمزمانی Check EMAIL_HOST_USESR in your settings, I think you have misspelled "USER" there.

Comment: @ابراهیمزمانی you can also accept my answer if it helped you, using the tick mark next to the answer :)